# Getting my Product object into an Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am pretty new to coding. This is my first class and it's an intro to Java. I am stuck on one part of the assignment - not sure where to go.

I have an inventory program that has a Product class and a Stock class. The stock class needs to be able to use the product object in an array in methods to 1)tell if a product is in stock w. its sku. 2) return quantity with sku  3)add or remove product from Stock.

It sounds simple enough but I'm not understanding it. I've been searching the internet and reading my book for weeks to no avail so I thought I'd give this a try.

My product class contains the usual get/set methods for qty, sku, price, name

This is my Stock class:

```
public class Stock 
{
private static final int MAX = 100;
int currentNoOfProd = 0; 
Product[] productsArray = new Product[MAX];

//I need an empty stock array constructor

/*  public Stock (int[] stockArray)
{
 this.productsArray = stockArray;
}*/


//method to tell if Product is in Stock with SKU

public void inStock()
{
    for(int i = 0; i< MAX; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("testing stock inventory\n" + productsArray[i].getSKU());

        if (productsArray[i].getQty() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("In Stock");
        }

    }
}

//return the quantity of a Product given its SKU
public void  qtyInStock()
{
    for(int i=0; i< MAX; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("in qtyInStock loop\n" + productsArray[i].getSKU());
        System.out.println("getting quantity qtyInStock" + productsArray[i].getQty());

    }

}


//add or remove a Product from Stock
```

}
My stock class is just me testing ideas to try and do /something/ but at this point I'm completely lost. This may be vague but I don't know how much more specific I can get.

I am hard coding the sku, name, price, and quatity in my driver program, if that helps, when I initiate a product object.

Suggestions would be wonderful or tips, anything really to help me move along and figure this out and learn. Thanks so much.

Comment: first of all, your methods should get some imputs. For example, your comment says "return ... given its sku", but yout not "giving" such value

Comment: Is using Collections (dynamic data structures) allowed in the assignment or do you have to use Arrays?

Comment: @MickMnemonic unfortunately we have to use arrays

Comment: Nothing unfortunate there, you need to learn how to operate with arrays before using "easy" data structures such as Lists. :)

Comment: Could you also disclose the `Product` class because it's quite relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers that hopefully guide you forward:

**1. Instance variables in the `Stock` class**

By default, you should always use the "least visible" scope, i.e. `private`, in your instance variables. This means that `Product[] productsArray` should be replaced with `private Product[] productsArray`. Variables in the private scope can only be accessed by the containing class, which is a good thing when the class is a part of a larger application and you are debugging things.

**2. Method telling whether a product is in stock or not**

Your `inStock()` method is currently neither using a "SKU" (Stock keeping unit) for input nor returning anything back to the caller. It would seem better to change the method signature to

```
public boolean inStock(String sku)
```

instead. The iteration over `productsArray` looks ok, even though you can make it even more concise using the `for-each` construct, which has been available from Java 5 onwards (the array knows its size after it has been created):

```
for (Product p : productsArray) {
  // you can use p.getQty() and p.getSKU() within the loop
  ...
}
```

Please note that because your array can/will contain `null` elements, you should check for `p != null` before invoking any methods on `p`. Basically you just need to return `true` from the loop when you find a match with a positive quantity and the given "SKU". Otherwise return `false` at the end of the method because no matches were found.

**3. Return quantity of a product**

The method signature should be changed to

```
public int qtyInStock(String sku)
```

If we assume that `productsArray` only holds one `Product` for a given "SKU", then you can simply iterate over the array and return the quantity of a product if one is found.

**4. Add or remove product from Stock.**

You probably want to split this requirement into two different methods: one for adding and one for removing stuff from your stock. For example:

```
public void addProduct(Product p)
```

and

```
public void removeProduct(Product p)
```

These are more difficult methods to implement, because they require manipulating the underlying `productsArray`. Also, in a real life application, the method would possibly throw an [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) if something unexpected happens (stock out of space, product not in stock etc.).

If we assume that your `MAX` array size is large enough, and that you only store one `Product` per "SKU" in the array, then basically you need to:

When adding a product: Iterate over the array and try to find a product with a "SKU" matching the input product's "SKU". If a match is found, increment the quantity based on the quantity of the input product; else store the product in the first available slot (having `productsArray[i] == null`) in the array.

When removing a product: if a match is found in the array, just set it to `null` using `productsArray[i] = null`.

Note that in these array-modifying methods, it is more practical to iterate using the for loop that keeps track of the index (`for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)`), which you already used in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Collection, e. g. `ArrayList<Product>` instead of `Product[].` Your stock would not have fixed size and you will get some useful API as for example `list.add(product),` `list.contains(product)` etc.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a list? while that probably would make more sense, I don't believe i'm allowed to use it.